# The Usual Suspects - Truth in Verbal Kint's Story

Tags: plot-explanation, the-usual-suspects

Verbal Kint (aka Keyser Soze?!) narrates 'the story' of what happened after their police lineup, few weeks back, that ultimately leads up to the finale at the ship. Verbal uses a lot of information from the pinups in the room where he is interrogated and forges his story. Like in the first heist pulled, they must have actually pulled the heist. But Verbal reads 'Redfoot' somewhere from the pinups and creates a fence with that character. So my question is which parts of that story actually happened and which were the parts he made up? How far is the story told by Kint to David Kujan true?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: @Mistu4u Verbal uses a lot of information from the pinups in the room where he is interrogated and forges his story. Like in the first heist pulled, they must have actually pulled the heist. But Verbal reads 'Redfoot' somewhere from the pinups and creates a fence with that character. So my question is which parts of that story actually happened and which were the parts he made up?

Comment: The man in the ship's room before getting shot says " I didn't tell them anything.. I don't open my mouth" That might be true as well
But it cannot feature in verbal's narration Why would verbal narrate this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only portions of the film which were not fabrications of Keyser Soze were:

1. The initial sequences showing the arrest of the gang,*sans* Verbal Kint.
2. The conversations between Agent Kujan and FBI Jack Baer concerning Soze.
3. The scenes of the ship after the the fire and explosion that destroyed it.
4. Agent Kujan's questioning of Verbal Kint
5. The scenes in the hospital with the survivor of the carnage at the ship
6. The end reveal sequence

It can be safely assumed that the entirety of the film besides the above were all the story created by Kint/Keyser Soze to explain what happened.

Answer (score 8):

It's kind of the point and charm of the film that your narrator is unreliable. All we can know for sure is that a boat was blown up, all of it's passengers were killed and that they were trading people when Keyser Soze was killing many men. Other than that, no other points of the story were qualified as true. There weren't even police reports for the New York's Finest Taxi Service heist. This is a great question. I would even venture to say that it is THE question. But it is totally unsolvable, I'm afraid.

Comment: Verbal claims that everyone in the heist crew was killed. He claims all but him were killed on the boat and Fenster a few days prior. But only Edie Finneran's and the witness on the boat and the hungarian's death is confirmed